# Is there WSDL-specific tool without mapping to POJOs?

Tags: java, wsdl

I need to access some web-services from java.
But it is an overkill for my task to use generated from WSDL java classes. I just need to get responce and pass it to the script, which will handle everything else.
Also it would be better not to generate classes for new data source but just add WSDL file for a new web-service data source and add new script for it.
But I also do not want to throw WSDL away, and reinvent custom configuration for describing this ws-data sources.
Is there any java WSDL-specific tool that can help me?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  You want to compose XML and `POST` it to the service's endpoint manually?

Comment: So far I hardcoded web-service's url and the request message :)

Comment: And I wand to get this info from WSDL but avoid WSDL to POJO mapping

Comment: I want somtething like: Tool tool = SuperWsdlTool.eatFile("wsdl.xml"); SOAPMessage responce = tool.composeMessageForOperation('some_op').callIt();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding entirely what you're trying to achieve, you don't need to use wsimport to generate proxy classes to call a service. You can use javax.xml.ws.Service.create() to create a service, then have jax-ws generate a dynamic port and use that. You can also create a Dispatch mechanism from there that you can use to invoke the service and will get you a Response that contains the payload of the message.

Without more detail about what you're trying, can't really tell if that's what you're implying you need or not. But sounds like it.

At an even lower level, you could create an HTTPRequest to call a service and pass in the appropriate payload, and that would get you direct access to the response. But that seems like too low a level, and using the Service class and Dispatch interface (from which you get the Response) gets you to the same core response data but handles the other service wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) comes with extensive support for testing WSDL / SOAP based services.